# How to adjust image height and width so that it does not stretch and its lower portion is only visible?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to figure out how can I adjust image width and height so that it does not stretch plus, its only lower portion shows. I have managed to adjust it, but i dont know how to show the only lower portion. For reference , i want to do something like we do in background-image `background-position: center;`. This is my code so far.

```
    <div id="featured-banner" class="lazy-load song-image">
    <img alt="featured img" src="images/U1NbAmCyHljBGOOHH28bSve3wBk9Fkjb.jpg">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.song-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 412px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#featured-banner img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding: 0px 15px 15px;
}
```

Comment: Setting the image width manually means that that it will stretch to cover `100%` of the width of it's parent div. What you need is `height: auto; width: auto; max-height:100%; max-width:100%;` in order to maintain the original aspect ratio. Then, you can position the image to show whatever part of it you prefer. Can you change the relative link for the image file and also  upload and example of what part of the image you'd like to show?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `object-fit` and `object-position` css properties.

Good CSS Tricks [article](https://css-tricks.com/on-object-fit-and-object-position/) on this.

Answer (score 0):

I created a plunker as i understand your issue, check this and let me know that it is what you want. Here is the link - https://plnkr.co/edit/50rZCpPTFKOR0g6QCnZf?p=preview

```
div{
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
div img{
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
```